# Regular/Validation Expression for ID no

Tags: visual-web-developer-2010

How would you write a validation expression for a single letter 's' either upper or lower case and '9 digits from 0-9' e.g. 's11058967'

Comment: In what language? What have you tried? The regular expression part of this is exceptionally trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression that start with character S and take nine digits i hope it help.

```
^[Ss][0-9]{9}$
```